# How to show Hindi text in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, utf-8, character-encoding, multilingual

I am trying to paste Hindi characters in an array with elements like
`String[] arr = {"आपका स्वागत है","आपका स्वागत है"};`
but its giving error i.e.
`"some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp1252" character encoding"`
 while saving this.

Answer (score 4):

Switch your text encoding to UTF-8.

In Eclipse go to Window -> Preferences, select General -> Workspace. From the Text file encoding dropdown, select UTF-8.[image]

Comment: i tried with this but it disturb the others language formates like spanish, italian, french...

Comment: Make sure the file is being saved as UTF-8. Go to File->Properties and check the Text file encoding property.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks i found the solution...

1. create an array under the value folder
2. Use the font that support Hindi under the assets folder
3. `textview.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Hindi.ttf"));` its working fine...

Answer (score 0):

You need UTF-8 encoding, not Cp1252, and Unicode.

Comment: i tried with this but it disturb the others language formates like spanish, italian, french...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i found the solution...

1. Create an array under the value folder
2. Use the font that support Hindi under the assets folder
3. `textview.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Hindi.ttf"));`

its working fine...