# how to write in hindi on text view in android

Tags: android, textview, android-resources

is it possible to write in another language font with in text view in android
for example i have created

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("HEllo Android");
```

here i have wrote Hello Android in English how i can wrote it in hindi language.

i have used image its working fine

```
 <ImageView android:id ="@+id/header2"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"

              android:gravity="center"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:paddingTop="0dip"

              android:src="@drawable/why00learn00spanish_index"
              >
   <ImageView/>
```

any help would appreciate.

Comment: Here is some old post which can help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789827/how-can-i-show-hindi-text-in-android-tablet

Comment: of course its possible ,either u can perform localization or directly set text into it tv.setText("हेल्लो");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the OTF hindi file and put it into assets folder. Run the code in an activity

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/hindi.otf");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
tv.setTypeface(tf)
```

Comment: i have tried this but its not working. @Nitesh thanks for reply any other suggetion

Comment: @varun: I think the code given by Nitesh is correct.I have tried this for Gujarati Fonts and it's working fine.+1 for this.

Comment: @Shashank_Itmaster : ok lets me try it with another hindi font.ttf i have downloaded it from net with it is not working let me try to download another font and check it again. thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course its possible.
of course its possible ,either u can perform localization or directly set text into it tv.setText("हेल्लो");  If you will images it will get blur