# Malayalam characters are not properly showing in iPhone , iPod

Tags: iphone, wordpress, character-encoding

I want to publish a site in Malayalam, site is implemented in word press. In standard web publishing method all Malayalam characters are not properly shown in iPhone , iPod, Android . Now-a-days most of them are using some specific font (MLM-Panini) in Malayalam Unicode method. If we use this specific font in Unicode convert method there will not be any character issue in android and iPhone.

Like  mathrubhumi website,they have published in normal Malayalam embedded method and there is some character issue on iPhone and iPad.

But in britishmalayali.co.uk they have converted Malayalam in some other format (Unicode conversion) and there is no character issue all devices.

So I have to do some thing like the above format. Please let me know if you can help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Currently not all android devices & iOS device support malayalam unicode font. To display malayalam font in this devices using HTML follow two steps,

1. Convert unicode font to corresponding ascii fonts as mathrubhumi done for there website for handheld devices(iOS & android),(My suggestion is use ML_TTKARTHIKA font, becoz its unicode to ascii converter code is available here)

 [Refer this link for more information:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026171/displaying-malayalam-unicode-fonts-in-android-webview/10720283#10720283)

2.Use fontface tag to display ascii encoded text in HTML page, which will render all characters almost in malayalam.

```
String malayalamAsciiEncodedText=OriginlUnicodemalayalamText.toLowerCase().replaceAll("അ", "A").replaceAll("ആ","B")
          .replaceAll("ഇ","C")
            .replaceAll("ഈ","Cu")
            .replaceAll("ഉ","D")
            .replaceAll("ഊ","Du")
            .replaceAll("ഋ","E")
            .replaceAll("എ","F")
            .replaceAll("ഏ","G")
            .replaceAll("ഐ","sF")
            .replaceAll("ഒ","H")
            .replaceAll("ഓ","Hm")
            .replaceAll("ഔ","Hu")
            .replaceAll("ക്തേ","tà").replaceAll("ക്തെ","sà").replaceAll("ക്ത്യ","ày").replaceAll("ക്തൈ","ssà").replaceAll("ക്ത","à").replaceAll("ക്ഷ്യ","£y").replaceAll("ക്ഷെ","s£").replaceAll("ക്ഷേ","t£").replaceAll("ക്ഷൈ","ss£").replaceAll("ക്ഷ","£").replaceAll("ക്ടെ","sÎ").replaceAll("ക്ടേ","tÎ").replaceAll("ക്ട","Î").replaceAll("ങ്കെ","s¦").replaceAll("ങ്കേ","t¦").replaceAll("ങ്കൈ","ss¦").replaceAll("ങ്ക","¦").replaceAll("ക്ലെ","s¢").replaceAll("ക്ലേ","t¢").replaceAll("ക്ലൈ","ss¢").replaceAll("ക്ല","¢").replaceAll("ക്കേ","t¡").replaceAll("ക്കോ","t¡m").replaceAll("ക്കെ","s¡").replaceAll("കൊ","sIm").replaceAll("കെ","sI").replaceAll("കോ","tIm").replaceAll("കേ","tI").replaceAll("ക്വ","Iz").replaceAll("ക്രൈ","ss{I").replaceAll("ക്രോ","t{Im").replaceAll("ക്രേ","t{I").replaceAll("ക്രൊ","s{Im").replaceAll("ക്രെ","s{I").replaceAll("ക്ര","{I").replaceAll("ക്യ","Iy").replaceAll("ക്കൈ","ss¡").replaceAll("ക്ക","¡").replaceAll("കൈ","ssI").replaceAll("ക","I")
            .replaceAll("ഖേ","tJ").replaceAll("ഖൈ","ssJ").replaceAll("ഖെ","sJ").replaceAll("ഖ്വ","Jz").replaceAll("ഖ്യ","Jy").replaceAll("ഖ","J")
            .replaceAll("ഗ്ലെ","s¥").replaceAll("ഗ്ലേ","t¥").replaceAll("ഗ്ലൈ","ss¥").replaceAll("ഗ്ല","¥").replaceAll("ഗ്ഗേ","t¤").replaceAll("ഗ്ഗൈ","ss¤").replaceAll("ഗ്ഗെ","s¤").replaceAll("ഗൈ","ssK").replaceAll("ഗൊ","sKm").replaceAll("ഗെ","sK").replaceAll("ഗ്വ","Kz").replaceAll("ഗ്യ","Ky").replaceAll("ഗൃ","Kr").replaceAll("ഗ്രൈ","ss{K").replaceAll("ഗ്ര","{K").replaceAll("ഗ്ഗ","¤").replaceAll("ഗോ","tKm").replaceAll("ഗേ","tK").replaceAll("ഗ","K")
            .replaceAll("ഘൈ","ssL").replaceAll("ഘൊ","sLm").replaceAll("ഘെ","sL").replaceAll("ഘോ","tLm").replaceAll("ഘേ","tL").replaceAll("ഘ","L")
            .replaceAll("ങ്ങൈ","ss§").replaceAll("ങ്ങെ","s§").replaceAll("ങ്ങേ","t§").replaceAll("ങ്ങ്യ","§y").replaceAll("ങ്ങ","§").replaceAll("ങേ","tM").replaceAll("ങൈ","ssM").replaceAll("ങെ","sM").replaceAll("ങ","M")
            .replaceAll("ഞ്ചൈ","ss©").replaceAll("ഞ്ചെ","s©").replaceAll("ഞ്ചേ","t©").replaceAll("ഞ്ച്യ","©y").replaceAll("ഞ്ച","©").replaceAll("ച്ചേ","t¨").replaceAll("ച്ചൈ","ss¨").replaceAll("ച്ചെ","s¨").replaceAll("ചോ","tNm").replaceAll("ചേ","tN").replaceAll("ചൈ","ssN").replaceAll("ചൊ","sNm").replaceAll("ചെ","sN").replaceAll("ച്ര","{N").replaceAll("ച്യ","Ny").replaceAll("ച്ച","¨").replaceAll("ച","N")
            .replaceAll("ഛൈ","ssO").replaceAll("ഛെ","sO").replaceAll("ഛേ","tO").replaceAll("ഛ","O")
            .replaceAll("ജ്ഞൈ","ssÚ").replaceAll("ജ്ഞെ","sÚ").replaceAll("ജ്ഞേ","tÚ").replaceAll("ജ്ഞ","Ú").replaceAll("ജ്ജേ","tÖ").replaceAll("ജ്ജൈ","ssÖ").replaceAll("ജ്ജെ","sÖ").replaceAll("ജ്ജ","Ö").replaceAll("ജൈ","ssP").replaceAll("ജൊ","sPm").replaceAll("ജെ","sP").replaceAll("ജ്വ","Pz").replaceAll("ജ്യ","Py").replaceAll("ജ്ര","{P").replaceAll("ജോ","tPm").replaceAll("ജേ","tP").replaceAll("ജ","P")
            .replaceAll("ഝൈ","ssQ").replaceAll("ഝെ","sQ").replaceAll("ഝേ","tQ").replaceAll("ത്സ്യ","Qy").replaceAll("ഝ","Q")
            .replaceAll("ഞ്ഞൈ","ssª").replaceAll("ഞ്ഞെ","sª").replaceAll("ഞ്ഞേ","tª").replaceAll("ഞ്ഞ","ª")
            .replaceAll("ഞൈ","ssR").replaceAll("ഞെ","sR").replaceAll("ഞേ","tR").replaceAll("ഞ","R")
            .replaceAll("ന്റെ","sâ").replaceAll("ന്റേ","tâ").replaceAll("ന്റ","â").replaceAll("ണ്ടൈ","ssî").replaceAll("ണ്ടെ","sî").replaceAll("ണ്ടേ","tî").replaceAll("ണ്ട്യ","îy").replaceAll("ണ്ട","î").replaceAll("ട്ട്യ","«y").replaceAll("ട്ടൈ","ss«").replaceAll("ട്ടെ","s«").replaceAll("ട്രൈ","ss{S").replaceAll("ട്രോ","t{Sm").replaceAll("ട്രേ","t{S").replaceAll("ട്രെ","s{S").replaceAll("ടൈ","ssS").replaceAll("ടൊ","sSm").replaceAll("ടെ","sS").replaceAll("ട്ര","{S").replaceAll("ട്വ","Sz").replaceAll("ട്യ","Sy").replaceAll("ട്ടോ","t«m").replaceAll("ട്ടേ","t«").replaceAll("ട്ട","«").replaceAll("ടോ","tSm").replaceAll("ടേ","tS").replaceAll("ട","S")
            .replaceAll("ഠൈ","ssT").replaceAll("ഠെ","sT").replaceAll("ഠേ","tT").replaceAll("ഠ്യ","Ty").replaceAll("ഠ","T")

            .replaceAll("ഡ്രൈ","ss{U").replaceAll("ഡ്രേ","t{U").replaceAll("ഡ്രെ","s{U").replaceAll("ഡൈ","ssU").replaceAll("ഡെ","sU").replaceAll("ഡ്ര","{U").replaceAll("ഡേ","tU").replaceAll("ഡോ","tUm").replaceAll("ഡ","U")
            .replaceAll("ഢൈ","ssV").replaceAll("ഢെ","sV").replaceAll("ഢേ","tV").replaceAll("ഢ","V")
            .replaceAll("ണ്മൈ","ss×").replaceAll("ണ്മെ","s×").replaceAll("ണ്മേ","t×").replaceAll("ണ്മ","×").replaceAll("ണ്ണൈ","ss®").replaceAll("ണ്ണെ","s®").replaceAll("ണൈ","ssW").replaceAll("ണെ","sW").replaceAll("ണ്‍","¬").replaceAll("ണ്ണേ","t®").replaceAll("ണ്ണ","®").replaceAll("ണേ","tW").replaceAll("ണ","W")
            .replaceAll("ത്ഥൈ","ss°").replaceAll("ത്ഥെ","s°").replaceAll("ത്ഥേ","t°").replaceAll("ത്ഥ്യ","°y").replaceAll("ത്ഥ","°").replaceAll("ത്മൈ","ssß").replaceAll("ത്മെ","sß").replaceAll("ത്മേ","tß").replaceAll("ത്മ","ß").replaceAll("ത്തൈ","ss¯").replaceAll("ത്തെ","s¯").replaceAll("ന്തൈ","ss´").replaceAll("ന്തെ","s´").replaceAll("തൈ","ssX").replaceAll("തൊ","sXm").replaceAll("തെ","sX").replaceAll("ത്വ","Xz").replaceAll("ന്ത്ര","{´").replaceAll("ന്ത്യ","´y").replaceAll("ന്തേ","t´").replaceAll("ന്തോ","t´m").replaceAll("ന്ത","´").replaceAll("ത്യേ","tXy").replaceAll("ത്യ","Xy").replaceAll("തൃ","Xr").replaceAll("ത്രൈ","ss{X").replaceAll("ത്രോ","t{Xm").replaceAll("ത്രൊ","t{Xm").replaceAll("ത്രേ","t{X").replaceAll("ത്രെ","s{X").replaceAll("ത്ര","{X").replaceAll("ത്തേ","t¯").replaceAll("ത്ത","¯").replaceAll("തോ","tXm").replaceAll("തേ","tX").replaceAll("ത","X")


            .replaceAll("ഥൈ","ssY").replaceAll("ഥെ","sY").replaceAll("ഥേ","tY").replaceAll("ഥ","Y")                                   
            .replaceAll("ദ്ധേ","t²").replaceAll("ദ്ധൈ","ss²").replaceAll("ദ്ധെ","s²").replaceAll("ദ്ധ","²").replaceAll("ബ്ദൈ","ssÐ").replaceAll("ബ്ദെ","sÐ").replaceAll("ബ്ദേ","tÐ").replaceAll("ബ്ദ","Ð").replaceAll("ന്ദൈ","ssµ").replaceAll("ന്ദെ","sµ").replaceAll("ന്ദേ","tµ").replaceAll("ന്ദ്രേ","t{µ").replaceAll("ന്ദ്രൈ","ss{µ").replaceAll("ന്ദ്രെ","s{µ").replaceAll("ന്ദ്ര","{µ").replaceAll("ന്ദ","µ").replaceAll("ദ്ദൈ","ss±").replaceAll("ദ്ദെ","s±").replaceAll("ദ്ദേ","t±").replaceAll("ദ്ദ","±").replaceAll("ദൈ","ssZ").replaceAll("ദെ","sZ").replaceAll("ദ്വൈ","ssZz").replaceAll("ദ്വേ","tZz").replaceAll("ദ്വ","Zz").replaceAll("ദ്യെ","sZy").replaceAll("ദ്യേ","tZy").replaceAll("ദ്യ","Zy").replaceAll("ദൃ","Zr").replaceAll("ദേ","tZ").replaceAll("ദ","Z")
            .replaceAll("ബ്ധെ","sÏ").replaceAll("ബ്ധേ","tÏ").replaceAll("ബ്ധ","Ï").replaceAll("ന്ധ്രെ","s{Ô").replaceAll("ന്ധ്യ","Ôy").replaceAll("ന്ധ്ര","{Ô").replaceAll("ന്ധെ","sÔ").replaceAll("ന്ധേ","tÔ").replaceAll("ന്ധ","Ô").replaceAll("ധൈ","ss[").replaceAll("ധെ","s[").replaceAll("ധ്യ","[y").replaceAll("ധൃ","[r").replaceAll("ധേ","t[").replaceAll("ധ","[")
           .replaceAll("ന്&zwj;െറ","sâ").replaceAll("ന്&zwj;േറ","tâ").replaceAll("ന്റെ","sâ").replaceAll("ന്റേ","tâ").replaceAll("ന്&zwj;റ","â").replaceAll("ന്റ","â").replaceAll("ന്&zwj;","³").replaceAll("ന്‍","³").replaceAll("ന്നൈ","ss¶").replaceAll("ന്നെ","s¶").replaceAll("ന്നേ","t¶").replaceAll("ന്ന","¶").replaceAll("ന്മൈ","ss∙").replaceAll("ന്മെ","s∙").replaceAll("ന്മേ","t∙").replaceAll("ന്മ","∙").replace("നൈ","ss\\").replace("നൊ","s\\m").replace("നെ","s\\").replace("ന്വേ","t\\z").replace("ന്വെ","s\\z").replace("ന്വ","\\z").replace("ന്യ","\\y").replace("നോ","t\\m").replace("നേ","t\\").replace("ന","\\")
            .replaceAll("മ്പൈ","ss¼").replaceAll("മ്പെ","s¼").replaceAll("മ്പ്യ","¼y").replaceAll("മ്പേ","t¼").replaceAll("മ്പ","¼").replaceAll("ല്പെ","så").replaceAll("ല്പേ","tå").replaceAll("ല്പ","å").replaceAll("പ്ലേ","ts¹").replaceAll("പ്ലൈ","ss¹").replaceAll("പ്ലെ","s¹").replaceAll("പ്ല","¹").replaceAll("പ്പേ","t¸").replaceAll("പ്പൈ","ss¸").replaceAll("പ്പെ","s¸").replaceAll("പൈ","ss]").replaceAll("പൊ","s]m").replaceAll("പെ","s]").replaceAll("പ്യ","]y").replaceAll("പ്രേ","t{]").replaceAll("പ്രൈ","ss{]").replaceAll("പ്രെ","s{]").replaceAll("പ്ര","{]").replaceAll("പ്പേ","t¸").replaceAll("പ്പ","¸").replaceAll("പോ","t]m").replaceAll("പേ","t]").replaceAll("പ","]")
            .replaceAll("ഫ്ലൈ","^vssf").replaceAll("ഫ്ലെ","^vsf").replaceAll("ഫ്ലേ","^vtf").replaceAll("ഫ്ല","^vf").replaceAll("ഫൈ","ss^").replaceAll("ഫൊ","s^m").replaceAll("ഫെ","s^").replaceAll("ഫോ","t^m").replaceAll("ഫേ","t^").replaceAll("ഫ്ര","{^").replaceAll("ഫ","^")
            .replaceAll("ബ്ലൈ","ss»").replaceAll("ബ്ലെ","s»").replaceAll("ബ്ലേ","t»").replaceAll("ബ്ല","»").replaceAll("ബ്ബൈ","ssº").replaceAll("ബ്ബെ","sº").replaceAll("ബൈ","ss_").replaceAll("ബൊ","s_m").replaceAll("ബെ","s_").replaceAll("ബ്രേ","t{_").replaceAll("ബ്രൈ","ss{_").replaceAll("ബ്രെ","s{_").replaceAll("ബ്ര","{_").replaceAll("ബ്ബേ","tº").replaceAll("ബ്ബ","º").replaceAll("ബോ","t_m").replaceAll("ബേ","t_").replaceAll("ബ","_")
            .replaceAll("ഭൈ","ss`").replaceAll("ഭെ","s`").replaceAll("ഭ്വ","`z").replaceAll("ഭ്ര","{`").replaceAll("ഭ്യ","`y").replaceAll("ഭൃ","`r").replaceAll("ഭേ","t`").replaceAll("ഭ","`")
            .replaceAll("മ്മൈ","ss½").replaceAll("മ്മെ","s½").replaceAll("മൈ","ssa").replaceAll("മൊ","sam").replaceAll("മെ","sa").replaceAll("മ്യ","ay").replaceAll("മൃ","ar").replaceAll("മ്മേ","t½").replaceAll("മ്മ","½").replaceAll("മോ","tam").replaceAll("മേ","ta").replaceAll("മ","a")
            .replaceAll("ല്യ","ey").replaceAll("ര്യ","cy").replaceAll("ഷ്യ","jy").replaceAll("ഹ്യ","ly").replaceAll("സ്യേ","tky").replaceAll("സ്യ","ky").replaceAll("ശ്യ","iy").replaceAll("വ്യ","hy").replaceAll("യ്യൈ","ss¿").replaceAll("യ്യെ","s¿").replaceAll("യോ","tbm").replaceAll("യൈ","ssb").replaceAll("യെ","sb").replaceAll("യ്യേ","t¿").replaceAll("യ്യ","¿").replaceAll("യേ","tb").replaceAll("യ","b")
            .replaceAll("ഹ്ര","{l").replaceAll("സ്രേ","t{k").replaceAll("സ്ര","{k").replaceAll("വ്ര","{h").replaceAll("ശ്രേ","t{i").replaceAll("ശ്ര","{i").replaceAll("രൈ","ssc").replaceAll("രൊ","scm").replaceAll("രെ","sc").replaceAll("ര്വ","cz").replaceAll("ര്&zwj;","À").replaceAll("ര്‍","À").replaceAll("ര്യ","cy").replaceAll("രോ","tcm").replaceAll("രേ","tc").replaceAll("ര","c")
            .replaceAll("റ്റൈ","ssä").replaceAll("റ്റെ","sä").replaceAll("റ്റേ","tä").replaceAll("റ്റോ","täm").replaceAll("റ്റ","ä").replaceAll("റൈ","ssd").replaceAll("റെ","sd").replaceAll("റേ","td").replaceAll("റ","d")
            .replaceAll("ഹ്ലെ","sË").replaceAll("ഹ്ലേ","tË").replaceAll("ഹ്ല","Ë").replaceAll("ശ്ലെ","sÇ").replaceAll("ശ്ലേ","tÇ").replaceAll("ശ്ല","Ç").replaceAll("ല്ലൈ","ssÃ").replaceAll("ല്ലൊ","sÃm").replaceAll("ല്ലെ","sÃ").replaceAll("ലൈ","sse").replaceAll("ലൊ","sem").replaceAll("ലെ","se").replaceAll("ല്ല്വ","Ãz").replaceAll("ല്ല","Ã").replaceAll("ല്&zwj;","Â").replaceAll("ല്‍","Â").replaceAll("ല്ല്യ","Ãy").replaceAll("ല്ലോ","tÃm").replaceAll("ല്ലേ","tÃ").replaceAll("ല്ല","Ã").replaceAll("ലോ","tem").replaceAll("ലേ","te").replaceAll("ല","e")
            .replaceAll("ള്ള","Å").replaceAll("ള്&zwj;","Ä").replaceAll("ള്‍","Ä").replaceAll("ള്ളൈ","ssÅ").replaceAll("ള്ളെ","sÅ").replaceAll("ളൈ","ssf").replaceAll("ളെ","sf").replaceAll("ള്ള","Å").replaceAll("ള്ളേ","tÅ").replaceAll("ളേ","tf").replaceAll("ള","f")
            .replaceAll("ഴൈ","ssg").replaceAll("ഴെ","sg").replaceAll("ഴേ","tg").replaceAll("ഴ","g")
            .replaceAll("ഷ്വൈ","ssjz").replaceAll("ഷ്വെ","sjz").replaceAll("ഷ്വ","jz").replaceAll("ഹ്വ","lz").replaceAll("സ്വേ","tkz").replaceAll("സ്വൈ","sskz").replaceAll("സ്വെ","skz").replaceAll("സ്വ","kz").replaceAll("വ്വൈ","ssÆ").replaceAll("വ്വെ","sÆ").replaceAll("വൈ","ssh").replaceAll("വെ","sh").replaceAll("ശ്വേ","tiz").replaceAll("ശ്വ","iz").replaceAll("വ്വേ","tÆ").replaceAll("വ്വ","Æ").replaceAll("വേ","th").replaceAll("വോ","thm").replaceAll("വ","h")
            .replaceAll("ശ്ശൈ","ssÈ").replaceAll("ശ്ശെ","sÈ").replaceAll("ശൈ","ssi").replaceAll("ശൊ","sim").replaceAll("ശെ","si").replaceAll("ശ്രേ","t{i").replaceAll("ശ്ര","{i").replaceAll("ശ്ശേ","tÈ").replaceAll("ശ്ശ","È").replaceAll("ശോ","tim").replaceAll("ശേ","ti").replaceAll("ശ","i")
            .replaceAll("ഷൈ","ssj").replaceAll("ഷെ","sj").replaceAll("ഷേ","tj").replaceAll("ഷ","j")
            .replaceAll("സ്സൈ","ssÊ").replaceAll("സ്സെ","sÊ").replaceAll("സൈ","ssk").replaceAll("സെ","sk").replaceAll("സ്സ","Ê").replaceAll("സ്സേ","tÊ").replaceAll("സേ","tk").replaceAll("സോ","tkm").replaceAll("സ","k")
            .replaceAll("ഹൈ","ssl").replaceAll("ഹെ","sl").replaceAll("ഹേ","tl").replaceAll("ഹ","l")
            .replaceAll("ാ","m")
            .replaceAll("ി","n")
            .replaceAll("ീ","o")
            .replaceAll("ു","p")
            .replaceAll("ൂ","q")
            .replaceAll("ഃ","x")
            .replaceAll("്","v")
            .replaceAll("ം","w")
            .replaceAll("ൗ","u")

            .replaceAll("ൃ","r")
                ;
```

Example **fontface** tag in HTML page:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: Karthika;
src: url(karthika.TTF);
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Hopes This may help you.. Happy Coding.. :)